# Modify CSS for WordPress.com Subscribe Button for self-hosted Wordpress sites

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, button, subscribe

I have used [this instruction](http://fgiasson.com/blog/index.php/2011/10/02/wordpresss-follow-button-for-non-wordpress-com-users/) to create a button with JavaScript and CSS that looks like the Subscribe button on Wordpress.com pages.
But instead of the Subscribe button I just use text.

I'm looking for support to modify the CSS code:

```
 <?php wp_footer(); ?>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 #bit, #bit * {}
 #bit {
      bottom: -300px;
      font: 13px Helvetica,sans-serif;
      position: fixed;
      right: 10px;
      z-index: 999999;
      width: 230px;
  }
#bit a.bsub {
      background-color: #464646;
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #3F3F3F, #464646 5px);
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3F3F3F), to(#464646));
      filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3F3F3F', endColorstr='#464646');

      border: 0 none;
      box-shadow: 0 -1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      color: #CCCCCC;
      display: block;
      float: right;
      font: 13px/28px Helvetica,sans-serif;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      outline-style: none;
      outline-width: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0 10px 0 8px;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #444444;
  }
#bit a.bsub {
      border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  }
#bit a.bsub span {
      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-clip: border-box;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: url("http://sacriba.bplaced.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Favicon_small.png");
      background-origin: padding-box;
      background-position: 2px 3px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 30% auto;
      padding-left: 18px;
  }
#bit a:hover span, #bit a.bsub.open span {
      /*background-position: 0 -117px;*/
      color: #FFFFFF !important;
  }
#bit a.bsub.open {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
  }
#bitsubscribe {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #464646;
      border-radius: 2px 0 0 0;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      margin-top: 27px;
      padding: 15px;
      width: 200px;
      float: right;
      margin-top: 0;
  }

div#bitsubscribe.open {
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }

  #bitsubscribe div {
      overflow: hidden;
  }

  #bit h3, #bit #bitsubscribe h3 {
      color: #fff;
      font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin: 0 0 0.5em !important;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #333333;
  }

#bit #bitsubscribe p {
      font: 300 15px/1.3em Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
      margin: 0 0 1em;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #333333;
  }

  #bitsubscribe p a {
      margin: 20px 0 0;
      color: #FF7A3D;
      display: block;
  }

  #bit #bitsubscribe p.bit-follow-count {
      font-size: 13px;
  }
#bitsubscribe.open {
      display: block;
  }
#bitsubscribe #bsub-credit {
      border-top: 1px solid #3C3C3C;
      font: 11px Helvetica,sans-serif;
      margin: 0 0 -15px;
      padding: 7px 0;
      text-align: center;
  }
#bitsubscribe #bsub-credit a {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
      color: #AAAAAA;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #262626;
  }
#bitsubscribe #bsub-credit a:hover {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
      color: #FFFFFF;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
      easeOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
          return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t + 1) + b;
      }
  });
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      var isopen = false,
          bitHeight = jQuery('#bitsubscribe').height();
      setTimeout(function () {
          jQuery('#bit').animate({
              bottom: '-' + bitHeight - 30 + 'px'
          }, 200);
      }, 300);
      jQuery('#bit a.bsub').click(function () {
          if (!isopen) {
              isopen = true;
              jQuery('#bit a.bsub').addClass('open');
              jQuery('#bit #bitsubscribe').addClass('open')
              jQuery('#bit').stop();
              jQuery('#bit').animate({
                  bottom: '0px'
              }, {
                  duration: 400,
                  easing: "easeOutCubic"
              });
          } else {
              isopen = false;
              jQuery('#bit').stop();
              jQuery('#bit').animate({
                  bottom: '-' + bitHeight - 30 + 'px'
              }, 200, function () {
                  jQuery('#bit a.bsub').removeClass('open');
                  jQuery('#bit #bitsubscribe').removeClass('open');
              });
          }
      });
  });
</script>
<div id="bit" class="">
<a class="bsub" href="javascript:void(0)"><span id='bsub-text'>Scroll</span></a>
<div id="bitsubscribe">
<p><a href="#">Raufscrollen</a></p>
<p><a href="#showcategorylist">Zur Artikelliste</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Text looks like this (lower right corner):
[sacriba.bplaced.net](http://Code%20on%20website)

1. Why is the orange text aligned left? I suspect some values for margin or padding are the cause but I cannot identify them.
2. How can I change the text to centered alignment (within the grey area)?
3. The CSS seems rather bloated for my purpose. Are there any selectors that are not needed any longer?

Please mention the question number before your answer for more efficient reading.

Comment: Please link your site or provide html. We need the actual code to answer your questions.

Comment: Link to original website added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for your 1 and 2: Your **a tag** should contain the properties display: block as well as text-align: center.

Answer for 3: Adjust #bitsubscriber **p a** margin to your liking to control how big the text appears.

Comment: You mean like #bitsubscribe a { display: block}?

Comment: Yes. And add margin to it to control how big the text is.

Comment: Both options didn't work. Any other suggestion how to center the orange text?

Comment: Add in text-align:center;

Comment: Tried that before, but the trick seems to be display: block AND text-align: center. Thx!

Comment: I edited your answer to include the relevant information from our discussion in the comments. Have a nice evening!